# I would like to do horizontal swipe in a carrousel by appium webdriverio using typescript

Tags: typescript, appium, webdriver-io

I would like to do a horizontal swipe in a carrousel by appium webdriverio using typescript. Any thoughts, guys? I only find solutions using Java

What would be the best function for this case?
Already tried:
swipe
swipeRight
moveTo
dragAndDrop